# Chat head on an iOS application like in fb messenger

Tags: ios

Is there a way to implement a chat head on an iOS application which appears system wide like in Facebook messenger app ?(on a non jail broken device)
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. iOS doesn't allow any operations outside of the app. (Except background operations, but they are limited and you have no way to show UI on Springboard)